# Azure architecture design for a load-balanced environment

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network

I'm new to Azure, and a little confused about cloud services.

I'm making a Testing Environment that consist of multiple instances (of the same VM) where each instance has a REST API server (Consisting of 2 API functions: *GetResults, SendFileForTesting*) and a load-balancer that distributes the requests upon the VMs.
In each VM there is also a worker that processes the received files and saves the results in a shared DB.
The goal is, for the file processing to be distributed on the available VMs and the results to be saved in a shared place (So that the "GetResults" request would send all of the results to the client)
This is how it looks:

```
[LoadBalancer]
     |
[Multiple VM nodes] - (API: GetResult, SendFileForTesting)
     |
[Shared Result DB]
```

The **question** is, what is the best way to deploy this on azure?
Right now, I'm trying to create a load-balancer that has 3 clones of the same VM with the same REST API server and another VM that holds the shared DB.
Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are the REST API VMs set up as a ScaleSet?

Comment: No, but I will look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, I think VMSS is the best way to deploy it.

First, create two Azure VM, one is shared DB, another one is API server. configure API server to connect to shared DB. then capture this VM. After capture completed, we can use template to deploy a VM scale set with this image.

More information about create custom image, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sa-copy-generalized).

More information about use template to create VMSS with custom image, please refer to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-vmss-windows-customimage/).
(this template LB rules is port 80, if you need more ports, please edit this template)

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Two questions: 1. Should the DB VM be in the same availability set with the scale set (Or must it be separate with its own public IP)? 2. If I understood correctly, First a load balancer must be created with the API VM that's connected to the DB VM (in the same set). Next the API VM should be captured and used as an image for the scale set that will be put in the load balancer instead of the single API VM. Is that correct?

Comment: @cydan 1, DB VM not in the same scale set. we can deploy it in Azure without public IP address, use Azure VM as a jumpbox. 2 just create Azure VM and configure on it, then capture this VM, then use template to create VMSS and load balancer. (use image to create azure vmss)